# Visual Studio 2017 cannot view all git history, only current branch

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

In Visual Studio 2017, no matter which Team Explorer entry I try or toolbar icon I click it will only show me history of the current branch, I can't get it to give me the equivalent of a --all, as shown in the image. I am eventually seeing other tracks once I merge them in, but it only ever wants to show the current branch history.

Is there a way to do this?

[image: VS 2017 with git log]

Comment: You can recover a lost account by completing the form at [contact](https://stackoverflow.com/contact)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible. I have it from a reputable source it is due to performance issues on the Windows, Visual Studio and Office repos where there are 1000s of active branches and 100s of ongoing Pull Requests. The UI would just end up way too cluttered and wouldn't have reasonable performance.

While this may not be true for your repo, the Visual Studio git integration must support those other types of projects too.

Comment: Thanks. I'll use the command line then. If only VS had a built in command prompt pane like VS Code ;)

Comment: https://jessehouwing.net/use-git-directly-from-visual-studio/

Comment: And https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/say-hello-to-the-new-visual-studio-terminal/

Comment: thanks. I found from that article that the nuget command window is just powershell so you open that and you can get the same effect.